# Windows emits an "error" sound when using the EurKEY keyboard layout

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout, typing

OS: Windows 10 20H2

Language setup:

- English (United States)

  US (QWERTY)
- English (Germany)

  EurKEY Keyboard Layout by Steffen Brüntjen

---

Example: Clicking on the Search box in File Explorer = Error sound on clicking the text field, typing works without issues afterwards.

In Chrome, clicking the search/url bar = No error sound, once I type the first letter, error sound, no error sounds after that*.

---

Some more info: Rearranging which language EurKEY is under doesn't seem to help. I tried using version 1.2 (previously 1.3 beta) but that doesn't help. Typing in Word or Notepad doesn't trigger the error sound. Switching the keyboard layout back and forth in an affected text input causes an error sound as soon as it's switched to EurKEY.

*When opening a new window of Google Chrome while the last one is still open, the error sound won't play again in the search bar. Only if the keyboard layout is changed back and forth or all windows have previously been closed the error sound plays.

Comment: Does the issue occur on other system version such as Windows 10 version 2004 or others? If you have upgrade your system version, then issue occur on this new system, we could contact with keyboard support to check if any keyboard driver was released for Windows 10 20H2.

Comment: I highly doubt this is a driver issue. As far as I know my keyboard is plug and play (driver less).

Also this only happens when using EurKEY, I haven't had this issue with other keyboard layouts.

Comment: plug and play device use driver which located in Windows system, so that some times as  system updated but those drivers located in system not updated, it will occur compatibility issue when use them. If we tick update driver in device manger, it will download driver from Windows driver store, which device vendor need to upload and accept Microsoft verification and test when upload their, so that it will a delay than vendor website. Try to go device website and download latest driver to check if issue persists.

Comment: My keyboard is using the standard Microsoft HID Keyboard Device driver (i.e. no potentially incompatible third party driver), and there seems to be no update available.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem was changing the windows language to English, too. (not only the keyboard language)

Edit: Okay somehow after restarting the pc the alert sound appears again, still searching for a solution.
Edit2: I deactivated my keyboard software from autostart now (in task-manager settings), uninstalled EURKey 1.3 and installed EURKey 1.2, changed Windows language to English (US) and restarted my PC. For now the error sound is gone.